# Hilt: provide ViewModel inside a module instead of using annotations

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Using Hilt, injection of dependencies of a view model can be achieved using:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val accountService: AccountService) : ViewModel() {
    // ...
}
```

But to me it is a little bit ugly to clutter everything with those annotations. Is it possible to achieve DI using a module definition, something like:

```
// Modules.kt
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ViewModelsModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideAccountService(): AccountService = FirebaseAccountService()

    @Provides
    fun provideMainViewModel(accountService: AccountService): MainViewModel = MainViewModel(accountService)
}

// MainViewModel.kt
class MainViewModel(private val accountService: AccountService) : ViewModel() {
    // ...
}

// AppComposable.kt
@Composable
fun AppComposable(viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    // ...
}
```

The above compiles without errors but when the app is starting I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.app.MainViewModel
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.app.MainViewModel.<init> []
```

**Question 1:** is it possible to provide viewmodels without annotations?

**Question 2:** if it is, what am I doing wrong?